# How to define a direct association?

Tags: eclipse-emf, emf, xcore

According to the code below, could you please tell me how (and if it possible to) refer to the array defined inside the class `ComputationUnit` from the class `Service`?

```java
class ComputationUnit {
    contains Method[1..*] methods 
}

class Method {
    String name
    String signature
    Object sourceCode
    contains Parameter[1..*] parameters
}

class Servic e {
    contains Comment comment
    contains Parameter[1..*] parameters
    contains Contract[0..*] contracts
    refers Method[] methods //How can I refer to the array defined inside the ComputationUnit class?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. It doesn't make sense. There isn't just one array defined inside the `ComputationUnit` class, there's an array defined inside each instance of `ComputationUnit`. Which instance do you want?

Instead, you should write:

```
refers ComputationUnit unit
```

and then access the array as needed from the reference to the unit.